# LINQ query on ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, linq, arraylist

I am trying to figure out what the LINQ query is to do a calculation on an arraylist.

I have a Structure:

```
Public Structure CC
    Dim Con As String
    Dim Len As Integer
End Structure
```

This is populated and entered into an arraylist (shown simply) :

```
           cc.Con = "A" : cc.Len = 10 : aList.Add(cc)
           cc.Con = "B" : cc.Len = 10 : aList.Add(cc)
           cc.Con = "A" : cc.Len = 30 : aList.Add(cc)
           cc.Con = "B" : cc.Len = 50 : aList.Add(cc)
```

So how can I add A and B and get the totals using a linq query? Basically, I just Want it to spit out A = 40
B = 60

Any and all help is appreciated... I am stuck as this is what I normally use just for a list.

```
Dim groups = lItems.GroupBy(Function(value) value)
```

Comment: Please don't use `ArrayList` - it's so 2001. It's now 2016. Use `List( Of CC)` instead.

Comment: In case you can't use a `List<T>` (though I can't imagine why...), have you considered calling the `ToArray()` method on the `ArrayList`?  The ArrayList may not know about LINQ extensions, but a good old array should.  Though by all means if you *can* use a `List<T>`, do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List(Of CC)` instead of an `ArrayList` as they are outdated.

```
Dim aCount = Aggregate cc In aList Where cc.Con = "A" Into Sum(cc.Len)
```

Same thing for the B group.